# Warning: fopen(./channels/tvchannel/13_03.html) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: php

I'm executing a script (through php).

Whenever I execute it I get the following errors:

```
Warning: fopen(./channels/tvchannel/13_03.html) [function.fopen]:     failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/tvguide/public_html/script.php on line 189

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/tvguide/public_html/script.php on line 190

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/tvguide/public_html/script.php on line 191
```

First, I thought it was a problem of folder permission so I set all folders involved with 775.

The line 187 to 192 read as follow inside my script.php

```
$file_to_update = "$mypage/$suff/$txt_url.html";
if(!file_exists($file_to_update)) {
$stream = fopen($file_to_update, "w+");
fwrite($stream, $text);
fclose($stream);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I think, You are giving `w+` with opening file. But you are given only `775` permission to the folder as you said.

ie no write permission for public. Give `777` permission and execute. Findout if it works.